# What is mounted as / on initramfs when the specified root isn't available?

Tags: grub2, initramfs

I'm exploring an issue of the system not booting completely and leaving me in the `(initramfs)` prompt. The system is `x86` with `grub` as the bootloader.

The problem  seems to be that for some reason the hard disk can't be located and mounted.

However, regardless of not being able to mount `/` to the hard disk, something is mounted as `/`.

```
(initramfs) mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,realtime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,realtime)
udev on /dev type devtmfs (rw,nosuid,realtime,size=2016684k,nr_inodes=504171,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,suid,noexec,realtime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,realtime,size=404616k,mode=755)
```

So directories other than the ones explicitly mounted are coming from somewhere.

```
(initramfd) ls
dev    bin    etc    lib    var    run    scripts    proc
root   init   conf   lib64  sbin   sys    tmp
```

Questions:

- What is mounted as `/` in that case and where does it come from?
- Is this the initramfs image located at `/boot/initrd.img-4.9.0` on a bootable system?
- Does `grub` read it from the hard disk partition that it to become `/` once the scripts in initramfs are done?

Answer (score 1):

What is actually mounted as root is the `initramfs`.

The confusion seems to arise from perceiving `initramfs` as an entity that executes stuff. **It isn't**, it is loaded after the kernel and is nothing more but a content holder, a file system. :)

Once `initramfs` is mounted it contains kernel modules and scripts that help the kernel reach it's full potential without being a giant binary blob.

You can perceive `initramfs` as a USB stick that is "plugged" by `grub` and passed to the kernel to be mounted as the initial `/`.

Comment: You messed up initrd on Centos/RHEL/SL distro and initramfs on Ubuntu/Debian distro.There is last step of compiling kernel : # mkinitramfs -o /boot/initramfs-kernel version.img kernel-version on ubuntu. For Centos/RHEL : mkinitrd /boot/initrd-kernel-version.img kernel-version.

Comment: Grub bootloader read grub.cfg on /boot/grub2/ and showing grub menu

Comment: I find strange that you answer your own question but don't actually address your 3 sub-questions directly.